# How to force Google Maps to stay locked within bounds of a center column?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have been having trouble getting Google Maps to force to a certain location using CSS. [3 column layout](http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/f0dv3q3z/). I want it like this. When I insert the google map api link inside the center column it offset and ruins everything. I have been trying to figure out a way to get it to force it in the column, but still isn't working.

I would like it to be 3 column layout with center column been majority sized. Then a header and footer that would cross over the entire width.

The map is small for now, but I will want it to be the entire size of the center column.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: -apple-system, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 height: 250px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -125px;
 margin-left: -250px;
 text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: 100;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div#div_map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#map {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.container div {
 height: 100%;
}

div.container, section.main {
    height: 100%;
}

.column-left {
 width: 25%;
 left: 0;
 background: #00F;
 position: absolute;
}
.column-center {
 width: 50%;
 background: #933;
 margin-left: 25%;
 position: absolute;
}
.column-right {
 width: 25%;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background: #999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
 <script>
  function initMap() {
   var latlng = {
    lat: 40.816714399999995,
    lng: -120.90523610000001
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng
   });
   map.setOptions({
    streetViewControl: false
   });

   addMarker(latlng);

   // icon: 32x32
   function addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphics-vibe/media-pin-social/32/rss-feed-icon.png',
     map: map
    });
   }
  }
 </script>
 <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <section class="main">
            <div class="column-left" >Column left</div>
            <div class="column-center" >
                <div id="map" style="display:inline-block;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="column-right" >Column right</div>

   <!-- <h3 style="text-align: center;"></h3> -->

            <!-- <div id="map" /> -->
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? You forgot to close the `div id="map"` tag

I also changed the maps width/height to 100%/50% as well as

```
.container div {...}
```

to

```
.main > div {...}
```

because the first selector was affecting some of google map's elements.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: -apple-system, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 height: 250px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -125px;
 margin-left: -250px;
 text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: 100;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div#div_map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.main > div {
 height: 100%;
}

div.container, section.main {
    height: 100%;
}

.column-left {
 width: 25%;
 left: 0;
 background: #00F;
 position: absolute;
}
.column-center {
 width: 50%;
 background: #933;
 margin-left: 25%;
 position: absolute;
}
.column-right {
 width: 25%;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background: #999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
 <script>
  function initMap() {
   var latlng = {
    lat: 33.816714399999995,
    lng: -117.90523610000001
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng
   });
   map.setOptions({
    streetViewControl: false
   });

   addMarker(latlng);

   // icon: 32x32
   function addMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphics-vibe/media-pin-social/32/rss-feed-icon.png',
     map: map
    });
   }
  }
 </script>
 <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <section class="main">
            <div class="column-left" >Column left</div>
            <div class="column-center" >
                <div id="map" style="display:inline-block;"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column-right" >Column right</div>

   <!-- <h3 style="text-align: center;"></h3> -->

            <!-- <div id="map" /> -->
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Pat Oh Shoot. Right. Um, I am rather new to using CSS in general. When I correct it and make the map height/width both 100%. The div attached to the map is also height 100%. Stretching all the way down. How can I get it to not affect google map's div, but only affect my own, that being the columns. `div#div_map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: @Dez div tags are not self closing. @DKJ did you want the map 100% width of the column and 50% of its height? If you want to change the height of the map just change the `height: 100%` to whatever you want inside `#map{..}`